# Как получить координат дороги по заданным точкам с помощью google map api?

Tags: google-maps-api

В google map api есть возможность получить координаты маршрутов? Например, я задаю точки, а он мне возвращает координаты дороги как туда проехать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не совсем понятно про точки -- имеется ввиду цель маршрута, или массив точек по маршруту?

если речь идет о проложении оптимального маршрута из одного местоположения в другое, то вот мой код для одного из проектов:

```
function showroute() {
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var start = document.getElementById("routefrom").value;
var end = document.getElementById("routeto").value;
var request = { origin:start, destination:end, travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING };
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
        document.getElementById("other").innerHTML+=start+' - '+end+': <b>'+myRoute.distance.text+'</b><br>';
      }
     });
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

объект map должен быть проинициализирован заранее.
исходная точка маршрута заносится в текстовое поле с id=routefrom, конечная -- id=routeto, результат выводится в блок с id=other.
при вводе точек можно использовать детализацию вида: "дом, улица, город, район, область"

Comment: Точки это точка откуда куда, от гугл хотелось бы получить координаты маршрута, такое возможно ?

Comment: из переменной myRoute можно вытянуть